# How to secure an app built on phone-number registration?

Tags: security, authentication, registration, mobile-application

I want to build a mobile app that requires the number of the user to be filled in. After that, the phone number is sent to a server, the server generates a random verification code that corresponds to this phone number. Then, this verification code is sent via SMS to the user. Next, the user sends the verification code back to the server to ensure that he/she has entered his/her real phone number and not anybody's else.

I was wondering how do you really authenticate against the server if you only have a phone number and nothing else? I mean, in the typical scenario you have a username and a password that are checked on the server and if both of them are correct you can have access to the server. But in the case of a phone-number registration, you have only a phone number and if you authenticate with it only, it means that anyone who knows your number or just picks it out, can pretend to be you.

If you send some sort of a unique device ID, that means that you won't be able to use your existing account anymore, for example, if you happen to change your device with a new one.

So, how do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is always: client provides proof of something they have, in return they receive an identifying token. In a typical username/password scenario, this means the user proves that they have a secret (username + password), in return they'll typically receive a session cookie. In your case, the user proves that they are in possession of a specific phone, in return you give them a session token or other identifying token. The client holds on to this token and uses it to identify themselves to the server.

You're relying on the principles of the telephone system to make sure that's a uniquely identifying characteristic. You're basing your security on the assumption that only one person can receive messages for a specific phone number at any one time, and that you need to be in physical possession of the phone at the time of login to complete the proof. Of course you require this proof *every time the user logs in*. You do *not* let them register once with an SMS-loop, then afterwards you just ask them for their number and let them through.

If a user wishes to log in, they must proof they're in physical possession of the phone in question using the SMS-loop, then they'll receive a token. Period. That's the way it goes. No other way. The client (app) must hold on to the token for as long as it wishes to stay logged in. Obviously, you probably want this to last for quite a while and not require the user to do SMS confirmations all the time.

This obviously brings us to the topic of token theft, which can be a real issue. The token must be kept secret, since it essentially allows proof-less authentication. You may want to think about signing that token using some unique identifier specific to the device it's for, or encrypting it while it's stored on the device or other measures to make sure it can't be nicked from the device while it is stored on it.

Comment: Should I use the unique id of the device as a "password"? I mean that the combination of the phone number and the device id is harder to pick out. Meaning, when registering, the client sends the phone number and the device id (username and password), the server sends the confirmation code via SMS. The client confirms its phone number through it. Then, every time the user opens the app, he/she sends his/her phone number and device id to the server to get an access token. What about this?

Comment: If the phone offers a unique id in some way, you should certainly associate the token you're granting with that id. Note that this can't be the only identifier though, i.e. you can't treat that id as a username + password afterwards (what if a phone changes owners?). It just serves to further restrict an already restrictive system.

Answer (score 0):

As deceze points out, the best way to ensure the comm is safe is to use a temporal token signed with the device id. If the user logs out, changes device or reinstalls the app then they must go through the SMS verification process again to ensure the SIM cards is still in their possession. Keep in mind that the SIM card and device have different udids. To simplify this you can use RingCaptcha SDK on your app to generate the token, verify the user possesses the SIM card and store that token or id temporarily. Use the phone number as an identifier - similar to a username - and the temporal PIN code as the password. That pair plus the token will give you enough security that the device and SIM card are joined.